# Loading jar files dynamically using Inputstream

Tags: java

My application has plug in jars located in a folder of the main application

```
src
    app_package
    modules //plug in jars located here
```

My problem is I cant get the jars as files cause you cant have file objects when the main application is converted to a jar. Currently I am trying to obtain the jars by using an InputStream. Is there a way to use input stream to get the urls of all jars located in the modules folder?

**UPDATE**

I use java serviceloader in order to load the jar files. First I load all the jar files into file objects:

```
      File modules = new File("modules");
      File[] fileList = providerFiles.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
          public boolean accept(File file) {
              return file.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar");
          }
      });
```

The next step is obtaining the urls using:

```
        URL[] urls = new URL[fileList.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
            urls[i] = fileList[i].toURI().toURL();
        ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
```

My problem  is I realized I should use getResource() when accessing the jar files. However all I can accomplish is

```
       URL url = getClass().getResource(directory);
       InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
```

I am lost on how I can use the input stream to get the urls of all the jars.

Comment: You can use [File.list()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list()) to build proper path for each jar individually and then use some `InputStream`

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I think you should extend your question with code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear but it sounds like you have jar files inside a jar file. Is that correct? If so, that's quite an unorthodox deployment.

If you want to list the files inside a zip/jar file, you can use a [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html)

Comment: Is there a way to not have jar files in my jar? I am new to plug in development in java and I dont really know how to properly support dynamic loading of plug ins

Comment: Your build should create a .zip file of your application. The .zip file contains the .jar files. To install the app, you must unzip the .zip file. In this case, the .jar files will be available as `java.io.Files`.

Comment: Do you want to support true runtime dynamic plugin loading? Or are the plugins defined when the app starts and remain constant after that? If the latter, you can write a script to build your java classpath and get rid of URLClassLoader all together.

Comment: This is just a for fun thing but I already started on the dynamic plug in loading

Comment: Well... pretty much every java application I can think of has a lib folder with jars in it. It also has a .bat file (.sh file on unix) which builds a dynamic classpath from that.